# Missing \item error when using subsections in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I've been using sections throughout the whole of my worksheet but when I tried to add a `/subsection` after a normal `/section` I am getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.145 \end{flushleft}
```

The code that produces the error:

```
\pagebreak

\begin{flushleft}
  \section{Zusammenfassung}
  \label{sec:zusammenfassung}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
  \subsection{Aufgabenstellung}
  \label{sec:aufgabenstellung}
\end{flushleft}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about asking at [Latex dedicated SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set anything, since `\section`s (or `\subsection`s) does not set a paragraph until you type the first paragraph. So, use

```
\subsection{A section}
\label{ssec:subsection}
Your sub-section paragraph
```

Regardless, there is no need to use the `flushleft` environment to set the sectional headings, which leads to the problem in the first place.